# xamarin android player, not starting within Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I used Xamarin Studio and swapped over to Visual Studio for creating Android apps. Although my projects load perfectly, I can't debug them, whenever I click on **build** it succeeds but when it comes to starting the emulator it just does nothing.

This is the build log I got:

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========
```

I got nothing more, no errors, no indication of doing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Deploy 0` indicates that your Project is not marked as deploy in the Build configuration. You can set it in the configuration manager that can be opened via `Build > Configuration Manager ...`

[image]