# how to deploy android xamarin project to Xamarin Android Player in VS 2015

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When i try to deploy one android xamarin app to Xamarin Android Player i get this error

```
1>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: Phoneword, Configuration: Debug Any   CPU ------
1>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========
```

android emulator just works fine

[image: android emulator]

but from vs 2015 it doesn't start

[image: vs 2015]

what can i check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xamarin android player , not starting within visual studios 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420268/xamarin-android-player-not-starting-within-visual-studios-2015)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Whenever you see a message such as

`========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========`

This typically indicates your deploy was skipped.

You need to go to `Build -> Configuration Manager` and check the respective `Deploy` checkbox for your Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: Thanks for saving my day!

Answer (score 18):

Same as Jon Douglas answer.. But One picture tell 1000 words..

This answer only for lazy people like me..

**Step 1 : Build -> Configuration Manager**

[image]

**Step 2: Check the respective 'Deploy' button (In my case android project)**

[image]